# Access HoloLens 2 depth image in C++

Tags: c++, augmented-reality, hololens

I would like to access the depth images of the ToF of HoloLens 2 via C++. Is this possible via the developer mode?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible. You can access the depth camera by enabling the research mode on Hololens. Research mode is an extension of Developer Mode and give us access to key sensors on the device.

Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/research-mode) that introduces it and demonstrates the usage. And you can check the sample app on how to access the various Research mode streams in the [HoloLensForCV GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLensForCV).

Comment: thank you! However, the documentation says that at this time, the HoloLensForCV examples doesn't work on HoloLens 2.

Comment: @tech93 Please refer to the C++ implementation in the repo first, this sample still needs to be updated for compatibility with HoloLens2.

Comment: thank you! there is an information on the Microsoft site, that the feature will be available in the next month for the HoloLens2